# SQL query that randoms the id from all posible ids in table and outputs the rows containing that id

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query that selects all rows that have the `UploadedbyUserID = Rand()` (selects random id from possible `UploadbyUserID` in this case 4, 3 and 22 and only those 3 not 2 nor 5)

And if the rand gives 4 it outputs this:

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name |      date  | UploadedbyUserID   |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | 2222 | Testing    |                4   |
|    2 | Jack | description|                4   |
|    6 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                4   |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

This is the whole table

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name |      date  | UploadedbyUserID   |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | 2222 | Testing    |                4   |
|    2 | Jack | description|                4   |
|    3 | ffdsd| 2007-05-06 |                4   |
|    4 | dsm  | 2007-05-27 |                3   |
|    5 | dddd | 2007-04-06 |                3   |
|    6 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                4   |
|    7 | John | 2007-01-24 |                22  |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

and if it randomizes 3 it outputs this

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name |      date  | UploadedbyUserID   |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    4 | dsm  | 2007-05-27 |                3   |
|    5 | dddd | 2007-04-06 |                3   |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

Ask if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  This is one way:

```
select t.*
from (select uploadedbyuserid
      from t
      order by rand()
      limit 1
     ) u join
     t
     using (uploadedbyuserid);
```

First, let me say that this is weighted by the number of times that a user has uploaded something.  So, user "4" would appear a bit more often than "3", in your example.  If this is an issue:

```
select t.*
from (select uploadedbyuserid
      from (select distinct uploadedbyuserid from t) t
      order by rand()
      limit 1
     ) u join
     t
     using (uploadedbyuserid);
```

The next observation is that this can be compute intensive.  If you have lots of rows, there are various ways to speed these up.  For instance, one simple method would be to get about 1 out of 10000 rows:

```
select t.*
from (select uploadedbyuserid
      from (select distinct uploadedbyuserid
            from t
           ) t
      where rand() < 0.001
      order by rand()
      limit 1
     ) u join
     t
     using (uploadedbyuserid);
```

Comment: The First one did exactly what i wanted, Thank you.